# Check a file exist in the path in iOS using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I am developing a Cordova based application. I have the  path of the xlsx file present in the document directory. I want to check whether this file actually  exist in that path or not using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have the path to your file, you can use the File plugin ([documented here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file)) to check for file presence.